# Why does c# utf8-json need to serialize obj to utf8 byte[] and then utf8.getstring?What are the benefits of doing this?

Tags: c#, json

Why does c# utf8-json need to serialize obj to utf8 byte[] and then utf8.getstring?What are the benefits of doing this?

Utf8-json is one of the top speed JSON serialization tools in C #. When serializing json, the object is usually parsed into a string or char, then filled into StringBuilder, which maintains a char [], and finally calls the ToString () method to turn char [] into String. And utf8-json maintains a byte [], which first parses the objects into byte [] in utf8 format, and then calls UTF8. GetString () method on this byte []. I don't know the difference between this and other methods. Is it a performance difference? But through my verification, char [] -> ToString() becomes string faster than byte [] -> UTF8.GetString(). Why does utf8-json do this?

obj -> char[] -> string

obj -> byte[] -> string

---

I think I'm express wrong. I mean why the same serialization logic, UTF-8 uses byte [] to store, stringbuiler uses char [] to store, and UTF-8 is faster.

On. net fx, I spliced JSON into StringBuilder to compare performance with utf-8. The result is that UTF-8 is twice as fast. By reading the source code, I found that our serialization logic is the same, but why can UTF-8 be twice as fast as me? You know, UTF-8 also has a layer of byte [] to string consumption, and stringbuilder's ToString () is faster than UTF8. GetString ().

Answer (score 1):

In .NET as it stands, `char` and `string` are UTF-16 encoded, not UTF-8. In this encoding, there's exactly 2 bytes for each `char` or code-unit; where in UTF-8, there could be 1 or more bytes for each character. Generally the web has mostly standardized onto UTF-8 for encoding, so a raw write of `byte[]` into a stream is easier than converting the UTF-16 values first into UTF-8 then dumping into a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You mean neuecc/Utf8Json?

After serialize an object into a json string, usually you will send it, then you need convert the string into byte[] first.

So this is the benfit if the serializer can output byte[] data directly.